# How to retrieve message-id from spring websocket STOMP?

Tags: spring-websocket

SimpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSendToUser accepts MessagePostProcessor as the 4th parameter, but I cannot get message-id header from the callback.

Is there a way to get the message-id header sending to client on server side?

Comment: `StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message).getMessageId()` ?

Comment: It doesn't exist in the callback.

Comment: What? `message-id`? You have to set it yourself. It isn't mandatory header

Comment: @ArtemBilan it is mandatory, and it is set by spring internally.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Please, share more info what you have and what you try to do and it isn't available (yet)

Comment: I set MessagePostProcessor as last parameter when calling convertAndSendToUser, but in callback method, the message is not the one spring sent to client. I had debugged the source code, the message headers are modified after spring call MessagePostProcessor.

Comment: Great. So, the answer is "no", you can't get that answer from the `MessagePostProcessor`. Need to dig into the code to determine what can be done...